# What does 身の縮む思い mean?

Tags: usage, meaning

I found a phrase in one vocabulary book about the usage of `縮む`.
I am not clear on the meaning of this phrase:

> 身の縮む思い

I think it can be the same meaning as `恥ずかしい`. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 身が縮む思いをする/身の縮む思いをする means you're so afraid, scared, or frightened.
広辞苑 says "ちぢむ[縮む]③恐れなどで体がすくんで小さくなる。身がすぼまる。「身が縮む思い」"

Comment: So,is it not same with `恥ずかしい`?

Comment: @NyeinNyeinChanChan-- I don't think we'd say 身が(orの)縮む思いをした to mean 恥ずかしい, we are ashamed or embarrassed... We'd rather say 顔から火が出る or 穴があったら入りたい. (Maybe you're confusing 身が縮む思い with 肩身が狭い?)

Comment: Ok,thanks.I made a sentence `彼はしかられて身の縮む思いをした。`.Is it Correct? (Can you give me a example sentence,please?)

Comment: Eww I didn't know the phrase can also be used to say you're embarrassed. (I just saw Goo辞書.) Then, 叱られて身の縮む思いをした might sound like you were embarrassed because someone scolded you...

Comment: How about "I felt as if I was shrinking up with fear.
あまりの恐ろしさに身の縮む思いがした. " (the 7th example sentence in this page. http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22with+fear%22/2)